# Unable to call rest web service from html form action attribute

Tags: java, html, forms, rest

I am trying to call rest web service written in java from html form

My web service code is

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

      @POST
      @Path("/hello")
      @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      public String hello( @FormParam("username") String name1) {
  return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
            + "<body><h1>" + "Hello from helpdesk" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
      }

}
```

And my html page is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action= "http://localhost:8080/helpdesk/rest/hello" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username">
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here in the html form, i have called the web service ../rest/hello.
I have referred example from http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/

Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: can you try changing Username: <input type="text" name="username"> to Username: <input type="text" name="name"> and see if it works

Comment: @Satya, Tried with that. But no change.Actually on clicking on submit button there no change in the url in browser like .../first.jsp?name=xxx something

Comment: your app server is running right ?

Comment: yes, I am using tomcat 7. When i run web service as standalone application without parameters like (removing @param and all), xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/helpdesk/rest/hello, then i get reply as html page which i have return in web service code

Comment: got it change <input type="button" value="Submit"> to <input type="submit" value="Submit"> as your form is not being submitted

Comment: Now i can see the url change but i get error, that "method not allowed". The url change that i can see is xxxx./helpdesk/rest/hello?name=adasd

Answer (score 1):

I see  multiple problems in your code. First one is the way you have put the mapping of your REST service path:

```
  @Path("/hello{name}")
```

I don't think you can concatenate your two path params, I assume it to be a typo and expect this mapping to be:

```
  @Path("/hello/{name}")
```

Second problem is with your html code. You are trying to send the name as a `FORM` param, which is good for `POST` requests and not for GET requests. `GET` request expects the params in the URL or path as you are expecting it to be in your REST service code.

Now you have two choices to correct the code. Either change your REST service code method to `POST` from `GET`. Or you can send the name as path param from your HTML to hit your service correctly and getting the parameter.

If you change the method to POST, you may have to change the parameter to `FormParam` instead of `PathParam`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I make changes in the code as you suggested. But i get error of "method not allowed"

Comment: I have edited the updated code. I think something goes wrong in parameter passing only. Firebug also not helping

Comment: @Optimus Try to replace your       @Path("/hello/{name}")
to       @Path("/hello") as you cannot send the name as path param to a POST request. Also you need to change the name of param to 'username' in your method signature i.e.   public String hello( @FormParam("username")

Comment: I am getting same error, Specified HTTP method is not allowed for requested resources. I have edited the updated code

Comment: @Optimus Remove the path mapping on top of your class i.e. @Path("/hello")
public class Hello

Comment: Then got the exception The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Comment: @Optimus alrite, in that case you can keep the class anottation but remove from the method. Because currently it is there on both and hence not reching the mehtod

Comment: That also not works, it gives error unsupported media type when removed @path from method

Answer (score 0):

In your code change the name of the textbox to name.
Also change the path above the method "@Path("/hello{name}")".

Try with this path and url in html."@Path("/test")"

URL : /helpdesk/rest/hello/test

hello - is root class finder

test - is method finder in the root class

Refer the link "http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial-part-two-web-parameters" for difference between path param and form param

Comment: Hi Veera, My class name is Hello, and the method name is hello So you mean to say, my url look like xxx:8080/helpdesk/rest/Hello/hello and Path annotation with the methods

Comment: But when i did this, i get 404 not found

Comment: Its not about your class name. Its all about the path name your are giving. Instead of Hello give the path name "hello". So your url looks like this "xxx:8080/helpdesk/rest/hello/hello"

Comment: did that but same problem exists

Comment: Are your getting 404 again ?

Comment: Could you please remove this "/{name}" and try?